# Other than saving variable states, what is good practice for onPause, onStop, onDestroy?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I am to the point in the design of my first application where I am going to go back through my code and implement the life cycle management. Other than saving state of variables, what are good practices for each of these methods?

For example: clearing animations?

I know the question is sort of vague, but am wondering what your "to-do" list looks like when you are implementing these methods.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Closing a DB connection.
- Stopping the media player.
- Terminating an active connection, if any

Depends upon the kind of application you are programming.

Comment: I see... would you suggest destroying data structures like queues/lists/trees and rebuilding them onResume() or is saving state enough? Not sure if destroying them ( when I say destroy I mean objX = null) would help preserve resources and keep the app flowing well or if the change would be negligible. Your thoughts?